# How to change field types for existing index using Elasticsearch Mapping API

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elastic-stack

I am using `ELK` and have the following document structure

```
 {
  "_index": "prod1-db.log-*",
  "_type": "db.log",
  "_id": "AVadEaq7",
  "_score": null,
  "_source": {
    "message": "2016-07-08T12:52:42.026+0000 I NETWORK  [conn4928242] end connection 192.168.170.62:47530 (31 connections now open)",
    "@version": "1",
    "@timestamp": "2016-08-18T09:50:54.247Z",
    "type": "log",
    "input_type": "log",
    "count": 1,
    "beat": {
      "hostname": "prod1",
      "name": "prod1"
    },
    "offset": 1421607236,
    "source": "/var/log/db/db.log",
    "fields": null,
    "host": "prod1",
    "tags": [
      "beats_input_codec_plain_applied"
    ]
  },
  "fields": {
    "@timestamp": [
      1471513854247
    ]
  },
  "sort": [
    1471513854247
  ]
}
```

I want to change the `message` field to `not_analyzed`. I am wondering how to use `Elasticsedarch Mapping API` to achieve that? For example, how to use `PUT Mapping API` to add a new type to the existing index?

I am using `Kibana 4.5` and `Elasticsearch 2.3`.

UPDATE
Tried the following `template.json` in `logstash`,

```
 1 {
 2   "template": "logstash-*",
 3   "mappings": {
 4     "_default_": {
 5       "properties": {
 6         "message" : {
 7           "type" : "string",
 8           "index" : "not_analyzed"
 9         }
10       }
11     }
12   }
13 }
```

got the following errors when starting `logstash`,

```
logstash_1       | {:timestamp=>"2016-08-24T11:00:26.097000+0000", :message=>"Invalid setting for elasticsearch output plugin:\n\n  output {\n    elasticsearch {\n      # This setting must be a path\n      # File does not exist or cannot be opened /home/dw/docker-elk/logstash/core_mapping_template.json\n      template => \"/home/dw/docker-elk/logstash/core_mapping_template.json\"\n      ...\n    }\n  }", :level=>:error}
logstash_1       | {:timestamp=>"2016-08-24T11:00:26.153000+0000", :message=>"Pipeline aborted due to error", :exception=>#<LogStash::ConfigurationError: Something is wrong with your configuration.>, :backtrace=>["/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:134:in `config_init'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/outputs/base.rb:63:in `initialize'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/output_delegator.rb:74:in `register'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1613:in `each'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:181:in `start_workers'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/pipeline.rb:136:in `run'", "/opt/logstash/vendor/bundle/jruby/1.9/gems/logstash-core-2.3.4-java/lib/logstash/agent.rb:473:in `start_pipeline'"], :level=>:error}
logstash_1       | {:timestamp=>"2016-08-24T11:00:29.168000+0000", :message=>"stopping pipeline", :id=>"main"}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't change the mapping of an index when it already exists, except when you create new fields to Objects or multi-fields.

If you want to use the Mapping API for that your request would look like this:

```
PUT /prod1-db.log-*/_mapping/log
{
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}
```

However I would recommend you create a JSON file with your mappings and add it to your logstash config.

A template file might look like this (You need to customize this):

```
{
  "template": "logstash-*",
  "mappings": {
    "_default_": {
      "properties": {
        "action" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "fields" : {
            "raw" : {
              "index" : "not_analyzed",
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        },
        "ad_domain" : {
          "type" : "string"
        },
        "auth" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "authtime" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "avscantime" : {
          "type" : "long"
        },
        "cached" : {
          "type" : "boolean"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And the `elasticsearch` entry in your Logstash config looks like this:

```
elasticsearch {
    template => "/etc/logstash/template/template.json"
    template_overwrite => true
}
```

Comment: tried `PUT /prod1-db.log-*/_mapping/log
{
  "properties": {
    "message": {
      "type": "string",
      "index": "not_analyzed"
    }
  }
}` but got an error from `elasticsearch`, ` java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid version format: {"PROPERTIES": {"MESSAGE": {"TYPE": "STRING", "INDEX": "NOT_ANALYZED"}}} HTTP/1.1`

Comment: @daiyue Have you recreated the index?

Comment: what do you mean by recreating the index? How to do that in combination of adding a mapping?

Comment: @daiyue Remapping an existing index is not possible (except some expections). Mapping only applies to an index which is being created. I would **strongly** recommend you go the route of using a template file beccause you then don't have to deal with curl and can edit changes really easily.

Comment: Tried the `template.json` in `logstash` as shown in the OP. I am wondering what does `"template": "logstash-*"` do? Do I need to modify it to fit in my index names?

Comment: Yes. It defines which index it should apply the mapping to.

Comment: Been trying the `template.json`, like this in my `logstash.conf`,
`output {
   elasticsearch {
     hosts => ["172.17.0.2:9200"]
     manage_template => false
     template => "/home/user_name/docker-elk/logstash/core_mapping_template.json"
     template_overwrite => true
     index => "%{host}-%{[@metadata][log_type]}-%{+YYYY.MM.dd}"
     document_type => "%{[@metadata][log_type]}"
   }
   stdout { codec => json }
}`.
But got a `File does not exist or cannot be opened` error in `logstash`, which is very strange.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121723/discussion-between-fairy-and-daiyue).

Comment: but even with a template, the current mapping for the current index cannot be changed, right? a new-generated index would have the new mapping

Comment: @sami Yes. Once the index is created, you can't change the mapping.

Answer (score 3):

If at all you haven't specified any mappings for your fields while index creation, the first time you index a document into your index, elastic search automatically chooses the best mapping for each of the fields based on the data provided. Looking at the document you have provided in the question, elasticsearch would have already assigned an analyser for the field `message`. Once its assigned you cannot change it. Only way to do that is to create a fresh index.